AWS - Cloudformation stack IAM role - optional disappears
I am experienceing this odd scenario that the IAM role i've configure all of a sudden dissapears in the console when trying to deploy a stack. I've used the same role for over 400+ stacks with the same role, but all of a sudden it just disappears if delete a stack then it re-appears. I couldn't find any limitation or anything regarding this. I've tried to create a new role with trusted relationship but still nothing works.
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]

}
Its on this step:


I think you're saying that if you have more than a certain number of stacks, the IAM role dropdown in the console fails to populate correctly. Have you reviewed the browser console and network activity to see if there are any errors? Does it happen in a different browser? If you have a good repo plus diagnostics, it would be worth raising a bug or support case.

Thats what I'm experiencing can't say for certain. Yes I've seen the console and network no errors is appearing. same occurrence on other browsers as well. I've tried to write a support case awaiting response for that. But gave it a try here as well :-)
